# Relating calculus application to similar triangles.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am having trouble with how to prove and show part (a).
All tips are welcome.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

[image]

The figure is a section of your cone and cilinder. We have:
$$
AM=r-R \qquad MN=H \qquad BC=h \qquad AB=r
$$

and the triangle $AMN$ and $ABC$ are similar. So....

Answer (score 0):

Considering the big triangle and the small triangle, We can write:

$$\frac{r}{R}=\frac{h}{h-H}$$

Therefore, we get:
$$r(h-H)=hR$$
$$rH=hr-hR \longrightarrow H=\frac{h(r-R)}{r}$$

---

Where, the big triangle can be specified by $2r$ and $h$, the small triangle can be specified by $r$ and $h-H$.